# Disable button unless specific fields have values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an ASPX form and I need to disable the submit button if any one of six specific fields are empty. I'm trying to do this via Javascript or jQuery, but so far I can only find examples of either a single field on the form being empty, or ALL fields on the form. In my case, I don't care about several fields - only the six specific ones.

So basically, I have six conditions and one action. I found one example, but it was stringing together six different IF statements. I'd like to find a more streamlined way if possible. So, for example, I might do THIS for a single field... but how to do it for field2, field3, field4, etc. as well?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit_btn').prop('disabled',true); 
  $('#field1').keyup(function(){ 
      $('#submit_btn').prop('disabled'); 
  }) 
});
```

**Using Javascript or jQuery, what's the most efficient way to disable an input button if any of six input fields is blank?**

Comment: You should post a "*[mcve]*" snippet of your code, in order that we can see what you're working with. Which `<input>` elements are required to have contents?

Comment: @DavidThomas - I just used #field1 as an example. Field1, Field2, Field3, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the same class name to all the elements and then do a validation foreach class element. Like in below code, i added the same class name to all the input for which the validation is required using `class="valid"` and then use the jquery **class selector** and the **`keyup`** method that you used to control the state of the button.

```js
(function() {
    $('.valid').keyup(function() {

        var isEmpty = false;
        $('.valid').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                isEmpty = true;
            }
        });

        if (isEmpty) {
            $('#button1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#button1').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    1<input type="text" class="valid" /><br />
  2<input type="text" class="valid" /><br />
  3<input type="text" class="valid" /><br />
  4<input type="text" class="valid" /><br />
  5<input type="text" class="valid" /><br />
  6<input type="text" class="valid" /><br />
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Test Me!" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements will allow it, you can use [HTML 5 field validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation). The browser will not allow the form to submit.

```
<form>
  <label for="choose">Foo</label>
  <input name="bar" required>
  <input type="submit" /> <!-- <--- This will generate an error message if the user clicks it when the field is empty -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the start of it correct; create an array with six variables, one for each of the fields, and create a new function to validate everything that is called on each keyup. So you would have

```
var[] array

$('#field1').keyup(function() {
    array[0] = $('#field1').val();
    validate();
}
${'#field2').keyup(function() {
    array[1] = $('#field2').val();
    validate();
}

...create one each for each field

function validate() {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(!arrays[i]) {
            $('#submit_btn').prop('disabled');
            return;
        }
    }
    $('#submit_btn').prop('enabled'):
}
```

What this does is it listens to the fields for changes and updates the array. A blank value is falsy so you can just go through the array and disable the button if it's blank or null or something. Break out of the for loop in that case; you don't care about whatever else. If nothing disables the button and breaks the for loop then it's valid and the button is enabled.

This approach is useful because it's easily extendable. You can just push extra things into the array if you want to check them without rewriting the validation function.

This assumes you do not want to just use standard form validation and do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class to each of the required inputs. Then check the length of that object against the length of a filtered object where value is not empty. Then you can use that condition to set the prop value of the button to true/false.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

**JQuery:**

```
$('form .required-valid').on('input paste change', function() {
  var $required = $('form .required-valid');

  //filter required inputs to only ones that have a value.
  var $valid = $required.filter(function() {
    return this.value != '';
  });

    //set disabled prop to false if valid input count is != required input count
  $('#submit_btn').prop('disabled', $valid.length != $required.length);

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <label>Field1</label>
  <input type="text" id="field1" class="required-valid" />
  <label>Field2</label>
  <input type="text" id="field2" class="required-valid" />
  <label>Field3</label>
  <input type="text" id="field3" class="required-valid" />
  <label>Field4</label>
  <input type="text" id="field4" class="required-valid" />
  <label>Field5</label>
  <input type="text" id="field5" class="required-valid" />
  <label>Field6</label>
  <input type="text" id="field6" class="required-valid" />
  <label>Field7</label>
  <input type="text" id="field7" class="not-required" placeholder="not required" />
  <button id="submit_btn" disabled>
    Submit
  </button>

</form>
```

**Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/q2msc80L/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_btn').prop('disabled', true);

  $('#field1').keyup(function() { // on keyup
    var value = $(this).val(); // retrieve the value of the input

    if (value.length == 0) // if the value's length is 0 (empty)
      $('#submit_btn').prop('disabled', true); // disable the button
    else // if not
      $('#submit_btn').prop('disabled', false); // enable it
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="field1"/>
  <input id="submit_btn" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Just **note** that the form can be submitted using enter key, so instead of checking on every `keyup`, it would be better if you check `onsubmit` instead.